# How to change the color of the placeholder for the Ant design DatePicker element

Tags: css, reactjs, ant-design-pro

Though this is a duplicate question none of the previous answers could help me change the color of the datepicker's placeholder. The other styles are being applied other than the `placeholder`'s color. How to implement this?

```css
.ant-picker-input input::placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: end;
  color:red;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[image]

The above image is the borderless, iconless datepicker that I have used.

```
<Space direction="vertical" size={12} className="grid-cols-1">
  <DatePicker
    format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
    disabledDate={disabledDate}
    disabledTime={disabledDateTime}
    placeholder="Schedule a Meet"
    showTime={{ defaultValue: dayjs("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss") }}
    suffixIcon={null}
  />
  <Upload {...props}>
    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
  </Upload>
</Space>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i use `!important`, it will change the color of placeholder.

```
.ant-picker-input > input::placeholder {
  color: red !important;}
```

You can wrap your Datepicker with `div` and with help of `less/scss` you can update placeholder code.

```
<>
<div className="wrapper">
      <DatePicker onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
 <DatePicker onChange={onChange} />
</>

// scss

.wrapper {
  .ant-picker-input > input::placeholder {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

If you not able to find any answer you can try this.